# Jquery ui Datepicker not working on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, responsive

I have a simple jquery ui DatePicker that works fine in my desktop browsers, but not on a phone(android, apple etc.) as in nothing happens when pressing the textbox.

using jquery ui 1.10.4

JS:

```
$(function () {
      $("#TextBoxDate").datepicker();
});
```

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="StdValidationGroup"
      Width="100px" TabIndex="12" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Anyone who has run into this problem?

Comment: Did you try adding ` <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>`
Note- you should have downloaded jquery.ui.datepicker.mobil.js in your project

Comment: Anyway jQueryUI datepicker won't be usable on a smartphone; you'd better use an `<input type="date"…>` instead.

You can switch at runtime using JavaScript and modernizr.

Comment: It actually worked on a phone, it was just a design blunder, there was an element overlapping the datepicker when in phone size. Thus making it unclickable.